# From where to download sitecore 6 starter kit

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

From where to download sitecore 6 starter kit. Link of SDN site does not work?

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%206/StarterKit.aspx) seems to work fine for me.

Comment: but i'm getting this page easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/318/1070882300.png

Comment: This probably means that your account has no access to that part of SDN, you should contact your local Sitecore representative.

Comment: This link i broen for me. The one supplied by Zooking works.

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://sdn.sitecore.net/downloads/starterkit600Rev090203exe.download) from [this page](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Resources/Sitecore%206/StarterKit.aspx) works for me, but you need to be logged in to SDN off course.

Comment: I'm logged in to but it goes to erroe page

Comment: That IS strange, are you using IE and have you enabled cookies? I guess it should work anyway but it couldn't hurt to try. Otherwise http://support.sitecore.net should be able to help you

Comment: you mean this link will only work on IE. I used IE 7 and getting this page http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/318/1070882300.png

Comment: RORL, IE... good one - link doesn't appear to work

Comment: correction, the second link to a page doesn't work, however the first one does (the executable, that is)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to SDN but you cannot download file using this link [This link](http://sdn.sitecore.net/downloads/starterkit600Rev090203exe.download) from [this page](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Resources/Sitecore%206/StarterKit.aspx) works. Contact your local Sitecore office, it probably means you have limited rights.

Comment: I'm logged in at http://sdn.sitecore.net/ but i'm getting this error "Insufficient permissions to access the file

Description: Sorry, you have insufficient permissions to access the file. There is no local office in my country
"

Comment: Sorry, it seem that I cannot link directly to download file since you need to accept license agreement. please click download link in http://sdn.sitecore.net/Resources/Sitecore%206/StarterKit.aspx

Comment: when i click on your link i'm getting this page http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/318/1070882300.png

Comment: You get that either because you have no access or your session is expired. If you can see http://sdn.sitecore.net/Resources/Sitecore%206/StarterKit.aspx this page there is a link to download. If you get Permission Denied on this page as well then you simply have no rights to download it. You should contact someone at Sitecore and ask permissions to download.

Comment: The download link works, but the page link gives a 404.  BTW, be careful with the Starter Kit.  It does not play well with Sitecore 6.4.1.  The XSLT generates validation issues.  If SDN hides the link, they probably have a reason for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

For permissions you have to pass the sitecore exams(Sitecore Developer Foundations for sitecore CMS, .Net Developer certification for Sitecore,...) after that they give permissions to your account.

Answer (score 0):

According to John West, the CTO of Sitecore, they [no longer maintain](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?postid=41468) the starter kit.

Note for this link: Yes, you will need to be logged into SDN.  No, you will not need to use IE.